# How is a linked list supposed to look when it is printed?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

I decided to create a linked list using Python. I have all of my functions (insert, search, remove etc.) and classes (LinkedList and Node class). I just don't know how to create the __ str __ method (the string representation) of a node and of a linked list.

I can't find an article which describes how a linked list is supposed to be printed (all the articles I found explain what they are, and what functions they normally have). With that said, does it matter if, when my linked list is printed, looks like this:

```
1, 2, "a", "d", True
```

or like this:

```
1 -> 2 -> "a" -> "d" -> True
```

or like this:

```
[1, 2, "a", "d", True]
```

? Is there a particular way which data structures have to be printed?

Comment: It shld get printed the way you want :)

Comment: I would like the third one, because it is a list at first place. Linked is just how the list been implemented..or you can check how other list implementations print look like

Comment: Like @Lokesh says, it's completely up to you. There's no standard way of printing linked lists, it depends on the goal of the print (debug? present for user see and react to? etc.)

Comment: If you don't have a particular application in mind, I tend to print objects in a way, such that I can copy paste the result into the code and initialize an object with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard way to print a linked list. Choose a format that makes the most sense to you.

I like to choose something that is not only readable but also usable. That way when I serialize it, I can easily deserialize it.

So, if I print an object like this:

> 1 -> 2 -> "a" -> "d" -> True

and I decide to manually change it to this:

> 3 -> 4 -> "b" -> "e" -> False

I'd have a way to easily initialize a new object with those values.

But again, there's no standard way. It's whatever's best for the situation.